# Android BLE disconnected when screen off (without charger)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, screen-off

It's working well on most Android devices. 
Other device's screen gets locked after 1 minutes BLE device gets disconnected,if device without charger.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: When you say that it gets disconnected without charger, you mean that if it is charging the BLE keeps connected?

Comment: yes, when phone is charging device state is connected

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

this might come from the `Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep` option (which might affect all radios) - as it seems this only exists in `8.0` but not in `8.1` (at least on the Pixel 2 XL, according to this [article](https://www.androidpolice.com/2017/10/25/android-8-1-feature-spotlight-keep-wi-fi-sleep-option-removed-pixel-2/)).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be having this problem because your app is not [properly configured to handle Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby).

While there do not seem to be any restrictions on using BLE itself, doze mode might be messing with the control mechanism for your bluetooth connection (ex: a background service).

To see if this is the issue, you can [whitelist your app](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#whitelisting-cases) manually via `Settings > Battery > Battery Optimization` and disabling optimization for your app.

Furthermore, as of Android 8.0, there are [restrictions on background services](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) when your app is not in the foreground. So, you may need to create a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) to handle the connection.

Comment: it's not working. I've tried add app to white list via settings and programmaticaly. Service is foreground too

Comment: @Kurrrrwa are there any error logs? Are you 100% sure that you aren't swallowing any exceptions?

Comment: havn't any error. log is clear. device disconnected only when phone is not charging. Service stay alive